# UDP broadcast via sendto() returns "Can't assign requested address" on OS/X but not Linux

Tags: linux, macos, sockets, udp

I am trying to broadcast a string via UDP using the sendto() function.

The code below works fine on a Linux box (e.g. a Raspberry Pi) but fails under OS/X on an iMac and MacBook Air.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  const char *msg_str = "hello, world";
  const char *bcast_addr = argv[1];
  int port = atoi(argv[2]);
  struct sockaddr_in sock_in;
  int yes = 1;
  int sinlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  memset(&sock_in, 0, sinlen);
  int sock = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if ( sock < 0 ) {
    printf("socket: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
  }

  sock_in.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(bcast_addr);  
  sock_in.sin_port = htons(port);
  sock_in.sin_family = PF_INET;

  if ( bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_in, sinlen) < 0 ) { 
    printf("bind: %s %d %s\n", bcast_addr, errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
  }

  if ( setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &yes, sizeof(int) ) < 0 ) { 
    printf("setsockopt: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
  }

  if  ( sendto(sock, msg_str, strlen(msg_str), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_in, sinlen) < 0 ) {
    printf("sendto: %d %s str='%s', sinlen=%d\n", errno, strerror(errno), msg_str, sinlen);
    exit(-1);
  }
  printf("message sent!\n");
}
```

My OS/X box is on a local network with an IP address of `192.168.0.4` and a broadcast address of `192.168.0.255`.  The output of `ifconfig en1 | grep broadcast` produces the following:

```
inet 192.168.0.4 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

If I run the code above above like this:

```
a.out 192.168.0.255 1234
```

The `bind()` and `setsockopt()` functions work, but `sendto()` returns `errno 49`.  My program prints the following:

```
sendto: 49 Can't assign requested address str='hello, world', sinlen=16
```

But if I run it like this:

```
a.out 192.168.0.4 1234
```

Then everything works fine.  But of course the broadcast only goes to the local box.

When I use the broadcast address (e.g. `192.168.0.255`) on a Linux box on the same network, it works fine.  On my Mac I have tried running both as a regular user and as root, with the same results.   I seem to remember this working a few versions of OS/X ago (I know it did not work on Mavericks).

Any idea what Apple is doing here??

Answer (score 3):

It looks like linux is just less restrictive. The problem should be with an attempt to bind to a non-local address 192.168.0.255:

```
sock_in.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(bcast_addr);
```

Why don't you use 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 as a source address?
Or if you want to bind just to a particular interface you can process information about network addresses and netmasks using e.g. getifaddrs/freeifaddrs.

Answer (score 0):

I need the address 192.168.0.255 because I want the message to be broadcast across the entire local subnet.

But I `y_ug` is right -- the problem is with the call to `bind()` on a non local address.  I don't need that call at all since all I am doing is sending.  In fact it makes no sense -- I must have copied that from some other code. For some reason, the Raspberry Pi (running Debian Linux) does not seem to mind and works just fine.  But the OS/X box gives the error above.

Answer (score -1):

UDP channels are in a higher range. Valid multicast range addresses from 224.0.0.1 to 239.255.255.255  --so I'm surprised your program ever worked.